# Partitioning for Lubuntu

Tags: partitioning, lubuntu

I am going through the Lubuntu 20.04 installation process using the installer, and when it comes to the "Partitions" section, I don't have the option to erase everything and just install Lubuntu on my machine.  All manuals I've come across display a "Partitions" section with several options, as apposed to just one.  I'm also not sure why it says "EFI" at the top instead of "BIOS"

I'm looking to replace windows on this computer with Lubuntu.  Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Most likely you have a partition mounted, as if any partition is mounted on that device, the "Erase" option won't appear. Exit `calamares` (the installer) and use *KDE Partition Manager* to check nothing is mounted, then you can re-start `calamares`.  See the *NOTE* on this page https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.3/installation.html of the manual which covers *swap* different to wording I've used.

Comment: There is also mention in the release notes (https://lubuntu.me/focal-released/ or https://lubuntu.me/focal-1-released/) though it's likely to have been missed as it was mentioned in a situation that wouldn't have applied to you.  Release notes would be were I'd check first, Lubuntu manual second.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: @guiverc All the manual says is "If all you want is Lubuntu on your machine, you can select the Erase disk button" which I don't have.  I took a look at the KDE Partition Manager and didn't see anything wrong

Comment: The note I was referring to was "*If you had a previous Linux install with swap you will need to unmount the swap. To do this run..*"   In *KDE Partition Manager* you'll see LOCK symbols on partitions that are mounted; ie. that's the problem (swap or other) that I was referring to, or my intention.  You could provide a link to the image you see in KDE Partition Manager if you have questions (I'd hope to see indications of issue there, if not I'd likely explore via commands)

Comment: @guiverc I haven't had a previous version of Linux installed on this machine.  It's only been Window which I'm trying to get rid of

Comment: I don't know what partition scheme, nor what partitions are on your machine (*swap* was used mostly as example), and some makes use a number of partitions (not just windows, but recovery partitions etc) that you'll get your best clues with easily in *KDE Partition Manager*, or via commands `fdisk` etc.

Comment: @guiverc Thank you very much for your help, but I may be fairly stuck.  I just looked at the release notes for 18.04 version and it doesn't seem to have this partition stuff.  Think I'm just better off going with that version?

Comment: No I don't; Lubuntu 18.04 released in 2018-April (thus 18.04) with 3 years of supported life, and no upgrade path (it was the last with LXDE). 18.04 used the `ubiquity` installer which looked different to `calamares` (18.10 up) but it's the ~same with different UI. If 18.04 installs, you could then install over it with 20.04 (how I'd use 18.04). You could try Lubuntu's discourse, but I've hoped to see what you're seeing (link to picture, fdisk detail). I recall detail about MMC devices & issues with calamares, but I can't find what I'm remembering (3x resolved posts on discourse are different)

Comment: @guiverc I was able to install 18.04 and then upgrade to 20.04 without issue.  Thank you for all your help!  Looks like I'm good to go